# How do I debug jQuery.post() with JSON as dataType?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, debugging

I tried to avoid asking questions here and use the search function all the time, but I can't really find a solution for my problem:

I'm using jQuery to execute a PHP script that gives me values, which I then use to change the content of my HTML elements. My code looks like this:

```
  $.post(
    "classes/Damage.php", {
        id: id,
        action: action
    },
    function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#element1").text(data.a);
        $("#element2").text(data.b);
},
"json");
```

My PHP looks like this:

```
  $data = array("a" => "info1", "b" => "info2");
  header('Content-type: text/javascript');
  echo json_encode($data);
```

The problem that I have is when my PHP script isn't working properly, the jQuery code doesn't execute and I have to manually search for the error. How do I debug this the right way?

Comment: The header should be `application/json` not `text/javascript`. Can you provide an example of what issue(s) you're trying to troubleshoot?

Comment: If your id and action variables are good, then try dump post data and die in php file, see if you get your variables. if they're ok then make sure the response from php file is fine. You could also add done() and fail() to your post method, if php fails you can handle it graciously in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow,

first of all, there are other handler-functions that you can use when firing ajax. 
Here is an example of a function I use:

```
var sendRequest = function () {

[ ... code goes here ]

$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/saveForm.php",
    data: {
        'repoSelector': repositoryName,
        'filepath': fileName,
        'name': autor,
        'client': kunde,
        'adr': adr,
        'adr_date': datum,
        'communicated': communicated
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function (response) {

    [ ... response was alright , try json-decode the response]

}).fail(function (jqXHR) {

    [ ... yikes! something went awry ]

});

[ .. other stuff happening ]

}
```

You should see that you first and foremost should invoke $.ajax() instead of $.post(). I tell you this because it is de-facto standart in our company, but it SHOULD be really just a better-to-read post-call. Note the type:post hint in the ajax-call, you could aswell write type:get here, so you'd not really need to change much in the function.

Try rebuilding your post with this script.

The next thing is how to debug stuff when using ajax:

If you press F12 in your browser, you should find a tab named "network", here you can see the actual scripts executed and their status codes. You will most likely find your script after execution here, and if you click onto it, you can see into the response from your php script. If, however, this answere happens to be empty, you'd have a first sign that you did something wrong.

Also, you can see that my ajax here has a fail handler already, and in the best (or worst, depends ^^) case your function jumps here when the request fails.

PHP Errormessages will go here, too, like database-queries that failed, although it is not really good practise to output stuff like error-messages to every user. Better write into a log file, but this is out of scope of this answere.

I hope I could help you

Comment: `$.post` is just a shorthand for `$.ajax` with `type` set to `post`, so there is nothing inherently wrong with using it.

Comment: good hint. i was unsure whether the fail and done functions would work with it, thus the tipp to call like this.... Also, it is "normal" practise for years now. I can edit the answere if this would clarify it